# Why form submit with redirect doesn't work?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular16

I have this  piece of code in angular 16:

```
<div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
<div class="text-center">
    <img id="logo" src="/assets/images/logo.jpg">
</div>
<div>
<form (submit)="login(username.value, password.value)">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" #username>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" #password>
    </div>
    
    <input style="background-color: #007b32; border-color: #007b32;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accedi" >
</form>
</div>
```

```
login(username: string, password: string){
this.auth.login(username, password).subscribe({
  next: (response: any) =>{
    if(response["token"]){
      sessionStorage.setItem("Authorization", response["token"])
    }
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/index")
  },
  error: (msg) => {
    console.log(msg)
    
  }
});}
```

Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "/index", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "login", component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: "prefix" },
      {
        path: "index",
        component: IndexComponent,
        canActivate: [IsAuthFilter],
        pathMatch: "prefix",
      },
      { path: "**", redirectTo: "/index", pathMatch: "full" },
    ];
```

Now, my problem is that if i use the input type submit and i call the method login() in this way, the form doesn't redirect on /index but on the same page.
Furthermore, in debug it redirects on "/index/, but later it returns back on login page.

I can't understand why.
I mitigated this in past using a simple button, but i don't like this way, i want to use a form.

Maybe i'm not using it in the properly way?!

Thanks

Comment: Can you also share you route config

Comment: of course:
const routes: Routes = [
{path:'', redirectTo:'/index', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path:'login', component:LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix'},
{path: 'index', component:IndexComponent, canActivate: [IsAuthFilter], pathMatch: 'prefix'},
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

Comment: I would say, that your `AuthGuard` says `false` and redirects you back to the login-page.

Comment: But why? I'm setting the token on the click button

Comment: check your guard and check if response["token"] it's not empty or undefined